# can't get value of TextInput with redux-form

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, redux-form

I'm using React native and I want to use **Redux-Form** to submit text from `TextInput` following [this](https://medium.com/wolox-driving-innovation/https-medium-com-wolox-driving-innovation-easy-forms-in-react-native-with-redux-form-1cdc16a9a889) article,
It works as expected if I enter the text, but when I set the `value` property of `TextInput` to some string, after submitting I get an empty object.

It only works when I enter the text, but not when I set it to some value.

here is the part of the  `TextInput` I use:

```
const titleField = (input, inputProps) => {

var myval = 'test';
return (
    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
        <Label style={{padding: 5}}>Task Title:</Label>
        <TextInput
            style={styles.inputStyle}
            {...inputProps}
            onChangeText={input.onChange}
            onBlur={input.onBlur}
            onFocus={input.onFocus}
            value={myval} // get {} when checking the log input after submitting
        />
    </View>
  )
}
```

Hope you can help me with that,
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by changing the functional component to a class component and used `componentDidUpdate()` lifecycle method to check if the props has changed when passing them to the component and call `this.props.input.onChange(this.props.value);` because `input` can be invoked with a value also, therefore `this.props.value` is passed.

From Redux Form API (Field Component):

> input.onChange(eventOrValue)
>   A function to call when the form field is changed. It expects to either receive the React SyntheticEvent or the new value of the field.

This is the whole class component:

```
class CounterField extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
      super(props);
  }

  componentDidUpdate(){
    this.props.input.onChange(this.props.value);
  }

  render(){
    return (
        <View style={{paddingTop: 20, width: 30}}>
            <TextInput
                name='title'
                onChangeText={this.props.input.onChange}
                editable={false}
                value={this.props.value}
                style={{fontSize: 20, textAlign: 'center', fontWeight: 'bold'}}
                placeholder={'0'}
            />
        </View>

    )
  }
}
```